# Getting Blank Option Value When Calling Recursive Function in N Level Of Category

Tags: php, recursive-query, multi-level

I am Creating Select Box with n Level Of Category But I am Getting Blank record 
I didnt find error What is the Problem.

```
$value = 'upload_files/';
echo $manage_folder->getFolderOptionListByParentId(0,$value);

function getFolderOptionListByParentId($parent = 0,$value)
{
        $html = '';
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from tbl_folder where folder_parent_id = '$parent'");
        if($query){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                $current_id = $row['folder_id'];
                $passvalue =  $value.$row['folder_name'].'/';
                $html .= '<option value="'.$passvalue.'">' . $value.$row['folder_name'].'/<option>';
                $has_sub = NULL;
                $has_sub = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(folder_parent_id) as total FROM tbl_folder WHERE folder_parent_id = '$current_id'"));
                if($has_sub['total'] != 0){
                    $html.= $this->getFolderOptionListByParentId($current_id,$passvalue);
                }

            }
        }

        return $html;
    }
```

My Getting Answer is Like Below

```
<select name="file_upload_dir" class="select_uplopad">
              <option value="upload_files/">upload_files/</option>

<option value="upload_files/eteste/">upload_files/eteste/</option>

<option></option>
<option value="upload_files/Munir_26/">upload_files/Munir_26/</option>
<option></option>
<option value="upload_files/Munir_26/munir1/">upload_files/Munir_26/munir1/</option>
<option></option>
<option value="upload_files/Munir_26/munir12/">upload_files/Munir_26/munir12/</option>
<option></option>

<option value="upload_files/Test_27/">upload_files/Test_27/</option><option></option>    <option value="upload_files/Kaushik_28/">upload_files/Kaushik_28/</option>
<option></option><option value="upload_files/32_abhisekh/">upload_files/32_abhisekh/</option>
<option></option>
<option value="upload_files/Harigopal_33/">upload_files/Harigopal_33/</option><option></option>
<option value="upload_files/34_test/">upload_files/34_test/</option>    
<option></option><option value="upload_files/34_test/dsds/">upload_files/34_test/dsds/</option>
<option>
</option>
</select>
```

I Got This type of Result So any solutiuon For this

Please Give Me

Comment: It would be useful to see some of your code.

Comment: If you aren't getting a result, have you tried running the SQL by itself and seeing if you get a result then?

Comment: i Am getting result but with blank Option

Comment: Is there a folder_parent_id = 0 in your table?

Comment: yes The Main Parent Folder HAs parent id - 0

Comment: Your closing option tag, change /<option> to </option>

Comment: Thnx Mario i Got my Fault :)